# How to SUM rows filtered by multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

Google Sheets question.

I have the following sheet (named "x") containing expenses:

```
Date        Sum Category
1/Jan/2017  100 red
2/Jan/2017  200 blue
3/Jan/2017  10  red
4/Jan/2017  20  blue
1/Feb/17    1   red
2/Feb/17    2   blue
```

I need to compute monthly totals, per category:

```
Month   Red Blue
Jan/17  110 220
Feb/17  1   2
```

My current solution is to place in each result cell something like:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(x!$B:$B, MONTH(x!$A:$A)=MONTH($A2), x!$C:$C="red")))
```

I am asking if there is a better way. I want to have a single result formula working over an array (maybe an ArrayFormula?!) instead of placing and customizing my formula in each cell.

Any ideas?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the basic idea of using pivot tables but not quite there because I can only get the month as a number so far

```
query(A:C,"select month(A)+1,sum(B) where C<>'' group by month(A) pivot C label month(A)+1 'Month Number'")
```

[image]

EDIT

The month number can be changed to a month name using an array formula and VLOOKUP but the formula is getting a bit long (my table of month numbers and names is in columns I & J)

```
=arrayformula({vlookup(query(query(A:C,"select month(A)+1,sum(B) where C<>'' group by month(A) pivot C label month(A)+1 'Month Number'"),"select Col1"),I:J,2,false)})
```

and you've still got to pick up the other two columns - this is the whole thing

```
=arrayformula({vlookup(query(query(A:C,"select month(A)+1,sum(B) where C<>'' group by month(A) pivot C label month(A)+1 'Month Number'"),"select Col1"),I:J,2,false),query(query(A:C,"select month(A)+1,sum(B) where C<>'' group by month(A) pivot C label month(A)+1 'Month Number'"),"select Col2,Col3")})
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, pivot table. But how to present only one row in the result? I am placing the results per category inside a more complex report...

Comment: You mean you want to select one row at a time, say February?

Comment: No, I meant one *column*, like one category red, sorry

Comment: OK well I might have to leave it there for tonight as it's getting late here, but as you've got the results in an array in the last formula, it should be possible to slice it by doing a match for the colour in the header row, then pulling out the corresponding column using index. But if you're going to specify the colour and the month, it might take you back to something really simple like a sumifs.